# Peut-on parler de "péché d'arrogance" ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Imaginons une personne qui s'est blessée en ayant pris un risque inutile pour impressionner son entourage (par arrogance). J'aimerais exprimer:

> Il a pris une mauvaise décision car il a été arrogant et ça lui a coûté cher

avec une plus belle tournure, je pensais à:

> Il a péché par arrogance et ça lui a coûté cher

voire même:

> Son péché d'arrogance lui a coûté cher

Toutefois, j'ai la nette impression que ce ne serait pas correct. Quel serait la plus "belle" manière d'exprimer cette idée sans prendre de tournure incorrecte ?

Comment: Ca dépend de ce que tu es prêt à sacrifier à la concision et à l'élégance. Tous les exemples cités sont corrects, dans leur genre, le deuxième étant une tournure plus courante. Mais le premier contient plus d'informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> L'arrogance a un prix !

La simplicité d'une tournure qui ressemble à un adage et qui dit tout sans tout exprimer est meilleure que des termes plus recherchés à mon avis. Je ne trouve pas les autres formulations incorrectes en ce sens que « ça lui a coûté cher » est usuel et qu'on déballe ça. Mais c'est peut-être davantage « [pécher](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9/1) **par excès** d'arrogance » et « son (excès) d'arrogance ».

Answer (score 1):

Une façon plus idiomatique de dire serait de parler de **péché d'orgueil**. Il est traditionnellement considéré comme un péché capital (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgueil)

Le sens est très proche de l'arrogance, et pour ma part, je n'ai jamais entendu la formulation **péché d'arrogance**.

Les formulations **pécher par arrogance** ou **pécher par excès de confiance** sonnent beaucoup mieux.

ci-dessous les statistiques d'occurence des différente variantes de péché d'orgueil/arrogance :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> Il a pris une mauvaise décision car il a été arrogant et ça lui a coûté cher.

Ce n'est pas cohérent ; « pour impressionner son entourage (par arrogance) » explique que le besoin d'impressionner est motivé par l'arrogance ; « Il a pris une mauvaise décision car il a été arrogant » : ceci nous dit qu'il y a eu une manifestation d'arrogance et qu'elle a eu lieu avant la décision d'impressionner, puisque la décision à suivi ( « car » : la cause est antérieure ou antécédente).

En s'en tenant à l'explication initiale on peut écrire quelque chose comme ce qui suit (l'arrogance est constante).

- Dans son arrogance il a pris une mauvaise décision  et ça lui a coûté cher.

ou

- Motivé par l'arrogance / son arrogance, il a pris une mauvaise décision  et ça lui a coûté cher.

2. 

Je ne vois pas ce qui pourrait être reproché à l'usage des mots  « pêcher » et « péché »  dans ces phrases puisqu'ils sont conformes aux définitions du TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9cher)) **pécher**
> **B.** − P. ext. [Le plus souvent avec un compl.]
> **1.** [Le suj. désigne une ou des pers.]
> **a)** […]
> **b) Pécher par qqc.** Commettre une faute, une erreur qui consiste en.
> • Pécher par excès de, par défaut de qqc.:
> •... c'est par excès d'activité et de confiance en elles-mêmes que pèchent ces nouvelles administrations; elles sont toutes remplies d'un zèle inquiet et perturbateur qui les porte à vouloir changer tout à coup les anciennes méthodes et corriger à la hâte les plus vieux abus. Tocqueville,Anc. Rég. et Révol., 1856, p.304.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9)) **péché** **B. − P. ext**. Faute quelconque (très souvent dans le domaine moral).
> •   Sa raison profonde (...) était simple, péché irrémissible en France (Stendhal, Amour, 1822, p.264).
> • J'estimais que le plus grand péché d'une femme est de n'être pas belle (A. France, Vie fleur, 1922, p.480).

• ([réf. 1, 1834](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_et_grammatical_de/qKVHAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&pg=PA563&printsec=frontcover)) Fig. Manquer à quelque devoir, etc. : *Pécher contre la bienséance, contre les règles de l'art.* En ce sens on dit également des choses : *Cet ouvrage pèche par trop d'esprit* — *Pécher par trop d'ornement*.

• ([réf. 2, 1857](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Divine_Com%C3%A9die_Traduite_en_vers_fran/yZ5WAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&pg=PA495&printsec=frontcover)) L'amour du bien peut pécher par excès ou par tiédeur : par excès , il engendre l'Avarice , la Gourmandise , la Luxure ; par tiédeur , la Paresse , à laquelle Dante prète ici un sens mystique , et qu'il rapporte principalement à l'amour ...

([réf. 3, 2007](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Petit_Larousse_illustr%C3%A9/AjkOAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&printsec=frontcover)) Pécher par excès d'optimisme

• ([réf. 4, 1910](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cat%C3%A9chisme_du_dioc%C3%A8se_de_Tulle/sxzMsALazrcC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&printsec=frontcover)) On pèche contre l'espérance de deux manières, par présomption et par désespoir. Pécher par présomption , c'est faire le mal et différer sa conversion sous prétexte que la bonté de Dieu nous sauvera toujours

• ([réf. 5, 2000](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Robert_Collins_super_senior_French_En/qEQjAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9cher+par%22&printsec=frontcover)) ...   pécher par orgueil to commit the sin of pride · pécher contre la politesse / l'hospitalité to break the rules of courtesy / of hospitality pécher par négligence / imprudence to be too careless / reckless

« Pécher par qqc » n'est pas seulement « commettre une faute qui consiste en qqc » (TLFi 1, réf. 5) mais aussi « commettre une faute qui  *provient de qqc* » (réf. 2 (tiédeur), réf. 3 (excès d'optimisme), réf. 4 (désespoir)). Donc, il ne s'agit pas d'un des péchés tels que la religion chrétienne les identifie (réf. 5, le péché d'orgueil, péché capital), et l'interprétation « qui provient de son arrogance » est sans problème. Il y a un détail qui ne donne pas à cette combinaison par coordination . La première indépendante est une explication de comment il a commis une faute et la seconde c'est la déclaration de la punition qui a résulté. de la faute. Le « et » de conséquence n'est pas justifié. C'est un peu comme « Il a tué parce qu'il est mentalement dérangé et la punition pour tuer est sévère.  ». Il faut donc changer la construction.

- Il a péché par arrogance et la faute commise  lui a coûté cher. (*Ce qui coute cher c'est la faute commise et non « ça » qui est « pécher par arrogance ». Il s'agit d'un « et » simple, mais l'interversion des éléments coordonnés n'est toujours pas possible: « faute » est justifié par « péché ».*)

3. 

> Son péché d'arrogance lui a coûté cher

• ([réf. 6, 1954](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Morale_sans_p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9/MO4H1ZtammkC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9+d%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9+d%22&printsec=frontcover)) Comme s'ils étaient coupables du péché d'exister

• ([réf. 7, 1984](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Somme_th%C3%A9ologique_Second_volume_de_la_s/c6oQAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover) ) Le blasphème ou péché contre l'Esprit Saint est - il identique au péché de malice caractérisée ?

• ([réf. 8, 1995](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_M%C3%A9moire_et_ses_traces_dans_les_litt/jVggAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22p%C3%A9ch%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover)) Sachant que cette lettre déclare une faute d'Adultère, on en conclut que pour Hawthorne cette tradition ne peut se saisir, transmettre et dramatiser qu'à travers le signe indélébile du péché de chair.

« Péché d'arrogance » semble idiomatique en cela que si ce n'est pas le nom d'un des sept péché capitaux, des références montrent qu'une variété de noms peuvent être utilisés ( d'exister, de malice caractérisée, de chair…).

La seconde possibilité est donc acceptable et pourrait avoir un certain intérêt, selon le gout de l'auteur, selon celui du lecteur.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette longue et complète réponse !